# Next.Js 14 sidebar with hamburger menu

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js14

Im making a chat app. I have a sidebar which displays the chats with your already created conversations. I want to make this sidebar responsive (like closing and opening it on mobile)

I have this code (Sidebar.tsx):

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import Chats from './Chats'
import ChatsSkeleton from './ChatsSkeleton'
import AddButton from './AddButton'

export default function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <aside className="w-[400px] bg-gray-900 h-[calc(100vh-100px)] mt-[30px] flex flex-col p-4 gap-3 rounded-r-xl max-[700px]:fixed z-10">
        <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
            <h1 className="text-2xl">Conversations</h1>
            <AddButton />
        </div>

        <Suspense fallback={<ChatsSkeleton />} children={<Chats />}>
        </Suspense>
    </aside>
  )
}
```

Also I have the Chats.tsx component where it fetches all the data:

```
import React from 'react'
import Chat from './Chat';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from '../utils/auth';
import { getChats } from '../actions';

export default async function Chats() {
    const chats = await getChats();
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    return (
        <div>
            {chats.map((chat: any) => (
                <Chat
                    key={chat.id}
                    name={chat.users.filter((user: any) => user.id !== session?.user.id)[0].name}
                    id={chat.id}
                    image={chat.users.filter((user: any) => user.id !== session?.user.id)[0].imageUrl}
                    lastMessage={chat.messages.length > 0 ? chat.messages[chat.messages.length - 1].text : 'No messages yet...'}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The data is being fetched with a new Server Action (actions.ts):

```
"use server"

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache"
import { authOptions } from "./utils/auth";

export async function getChats() {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/chats/', {
        headers: {
            'authorization': session?.user.token as string,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        next: {
            tags: ['chats']
        }
    })

    // handle unauthorized
    if (res.status === 401) {
        return []
    }

    const { data } = await res.json()

    return data
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You need to use `md:` tags before your tailwind tags for the necessary components, _probably just for the Sidebar component_.

Comment: @chagatai i know that but I want to be able to close and open the sidebar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anyways, I turned my component to a Client Component instead. Its a little bit slower but its okay i think.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would be great to see the updated code in the answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to implement it like a hamburger menu and toggle it on and off by using a button.

You can do it by using the state hook (call it a **drawer**). Here is a simplified example (*in JavaScript*):

```
import { Menu2 as MenuIcon, X as XIcon } from "tabler-icons-react";

const [drawer, setDrawer] = useState(false);

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDrawer(true);
        }}
      >
        <MenuIcon />
      </button>
    </div>

    {/* DRAWER */}
    {drawer && (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p className="text-2xl">Menu</p>

          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setDrawer(false);
            }}
          >
            <XIcon />
          </button>
        </div>
        {/* REST OF THE SIDEBAR ITEMS */}
      )}

    {/* DESKTOP SIDEBAR ITEMS */}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

This code is not ready for copy-paste to your code but it can show an examle for how to close and open it.

Comment: I know this as well, but as you can see im using Next.Js server components, where you cant add useState, you need to turn it to a client component, but i dont want to do that because it really slows down the entire thing. But thank you for your aproach!